# Set name filters only on files, not on dirs

Tags: qt4

I'm trying to get all files in a folder, recursively, but it looks stupid,

If I use `setNameFilters`, it would filter folder name as well, thus if a folder has no files inside, but only sub folders, the loop would fail. So right now I'm doing the internal loop twice, one for finding all sub folders without name filter; one for all files with name filters.

What's the right way of combing them? I want all folders, and all files that comply to the filter (And I'll judge if it's a file or folder in the loop)

```
QStringList FileFind::dir2files(const QString &path)
{
    QStringList files;

    QStack<QString> stack;
    stack.push(path);

    while (! stack.isEmpty())
    {
        QDir dir (stack.top());
        stack.pop();

        foreach (const QFileInfo & fileInfo,
                 dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Dirs))
        {
            stack.push_back(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
        }

        dir.setNameFilters(_nameFilters);

        foreach (const QFileInfo & fileInfo,
                 dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files) )
        {
            files.append(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I won't characterize this as the "one true way", I think you'll end up with a cleaner solution if you recursively call your `dir2files` member function recursively (your use of the `QStack` to manage the directories was the first clue):

```
QStringList FileFind::dir2files(const QString& path)
{
   QStringList files;
   dir2fileshelper(path, files, 0);
   return files;
}

void FileFind::dir2fileshelper(const QString& path,
                               QStringList& files,
                               int currentDepth)
{
   static const int MAXIMUM_DEPTH = 40; // For example
   if (currentDepth >= MAXIMUM_DEPTH)
   {
      qWarning("Maximum directory depth limit reached.");
      return;
   }

   QDir directory(path);

   QFileInfoList list = directory.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | 
                                                QDir::Dirs |
                                                QDir::Files);

   foreach (const QFileInfo& fileInfo, list)
   {
      if (fileInfo.isDir())
      {
         dir2fileshelper(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath(), files, currentDepth+1);
      }
      else
      {
         files << fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
      }
   }
}
```

**Update:** Added code to limit recursion depth and limit `QStringList` copying.

Comment: Shouldn't I worry about limited stack size (that limit recursive depth) if I do so?

Comment: @warl0ck Yes, you could run into a stack overflow for a very deep directory tree.  The only way to handle it is to either stick to your original implementation (which would use a lot of memory for a deep directory tree, but hopefully not crash) or to place a limit on the recursive depth (I've edited my answer to show this).  This is one of those areas where you have to choose between readability and resource usage concerns.